# Angular JS: completing an ng-repeat to a specific number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create the following UI functionality:

[image: NGRepeat with specific cap]

The user has to select three images. An ng-repeat shows the images selected while leaving blank images for the remaining selections. I was able to make it work as follows:

```
<div class="tap" ng-repeat="point in points">
</div>
<div class="tap empty" ng-repeat="point in emptyPoints()">
?
</div>
```

Where emptyPoints is calculated simply by making an array on the fly:

```
$scope.emptyPoints = function () {
    var arr = [];
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < 3 - $scope.points.length; cnt++) {
        arr.push({});
    };

    return arr;
};
```

Visually this seems to work, on the console however I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an explanation of your error you can read the next answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17430855/377651. Quoting from the same answer:

> Angular expressions are evaluated at least two times per each $digest and $digest can run 10 times at a time (when bindings need to be "refreshed"). This means that expressions will be re-evaluated many times over. This is one of the common pitfall with Angular. So you need to make sure you don't call functions directly in your expressions. Instead, have the function executed once, inside the controller, and than use the function result in the expression.

For your particular case you could use a single array with a fixed length (3) and empty at init, then when the user select an image you push that image on the array.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can do something like this

```
<div ng-class="point.selected ? tap : tap empty" ng-repeat="point in points">
      <img ng-click="tapped(this)">
</div>
```

wherever user tap on image

```
$scope.tapped = function(obj)  {
 obj.point.selected = true;
}
```